# How to reset to all privilages for root @ phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've created new db via phpMyAdmin and while editing db privilages clicked delete localhost privilages for this db (dunno why). Unfotunately all root privilages has gone. I can't see or create any db. Only root has admin rights. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Root has rights to set user privileges, I don't know how you delete this, Login as Root and go to Privileges tab and click add new user link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

http://www.wellho.net/forum/The-MySQL-Relational-Database/My-root-account-is-messed-up-what-can-I-do.html